# A simple proof that Every finite dimensional Hilbert space has orthonormal basis

Tags: hilbert-spaces

The proof that Every Hilbert space has orthogonal basis requires Zorn's Lemma. But if the Hilbert Space is finite dimensional, does it still require? If it doesn't, how could I prove in simple terms that Every finite dimensional Hilbert space has orthogonal basis? Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with  Gram-Schmidt algorithm? Because it is really all there is to it.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli No, but I can research and learn. Thanks you Very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a proof that an orthonormal basis exists without using Gramm-Schmidt.  We proceed by induction on $n$, the dimension of the Hilbert space $H$.  If $n=1$, then we choose our basis to consist of a single vector with norm 1.

Now for the inductive step.  Let $H$ be an $n$ dimensional Hilbert space.  Choose $v\in H$ of norm 1.  Let $H'=\{w\in H\mid \langle v,w\rangle=0\}$.  Then $H'$ is a Hilbert space of dimension $n-1$.  By induction, it has an orthonormal basis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1}\}$.  Now it's easy to check that the the set $\{v,v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1}\}$ is orthonormal.  It is therefore a basis for $H$ as it is linearly independent and contains $n$ elements.

**Edit in response to a comment:** By definition, a Hilbert space $H$ is a vector space with an inner product in which the distance defined by the inner product makes $H$ into a complete metric space.  It's clear that $H'$ is a vector space with an inner product.  Also, $\langle v, \_ \rangle\colon H\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, so $H'$ is the inverse image of a closed set ($\{0\}$) under a continuous function, making $H'$ closed.  Closed subsets of complete metric spaces are complete.  It's straightforward to verify that the distance defined by the restricted inner product agrees on $H'$ with the distance defined on $H$.  So the only thing that remains is to verify that $H'$ has dimension $n-1$; that is a fact about **vector spaces** and has nothing to do with Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Are there any quick ways to prove that $H'$ a Hilbert space of dimension $n-1$?

Comment: @erpxyr2001 See elaboration in response above.